# Magento Model source model - Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object error

Tags: magento

I'm trying to set a source_model on a custom module in Magento.
module is in local/Bitstream/Selfawb
in system.xml I have this:

```
                        <email_type translate="label">
                        <label>Email Type</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>bitstream/source_emailType</source_model>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </email_type>
```

And EmailType.php is in /local/Bitstream/Selfawb/Model/EmailType.php with the folowing code:

```
class Bitstream_Selfawb_Model_Source_EmailType{

public function toOptionArray(){
    return array(
        array('value'=>'mobile', 'label'=>Mage::helper('mailchimp')->__('MOBILE')),
    );
}
```

}

The problem is I get this error in browser: Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the model file path in the question what you are actually using or is it a typo?

Comment: damn, I was so pissed because wasn't working that I made that noob mistake. Thanks for pointing this clockworkgeek. It's all good now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is the path `/local/Bitstream/Selfawb/Model/EmailType.php` should have a "Source" in it.
`/local/Bitstream/Selfawb/Model/Source/EmailType.php`